# How create a lib file while creating exe file

Tags: visual-c++, build-process

I have an legacy application which builds into exe.
I am using Visual Studio 6.0 and the application is an c++ application. It used many lib files, built in VS6.0. Now i need to use the api's which in the executable. I want to create a lib file while it is creating an exe. I cannot change the code of the legacy application.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
AH

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate library project and add any source files with APIs you want to reuse into it. It's probably cleaner to also remove those files from the exe project and make the exe project depend on the library project, but this isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: Hi,
But the exe project is production code and should not be modified. Without modifying the production code and the project, i need to create the library. I can modify the project settings but i should not remove any files. 
Any way to generate library by modifying the settings?.

Comment: Then ignore my second sentence.